# String "</script>" causing error

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why the string `"</script>"` is giving me the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I only see the error when I declare the variable inline HTML. If I declare the variable in the console it doesn't give me any trouble.

I also noticed that `"</scrip>"` and other letter combinations do not give the error. Is there something special about that string that is causing this? I'm stumped.

```html
<script>
  var thing = "</script>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually just to escape the slash:

```
var thing = "<\/script>";
```

Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479554/3498950